# Free public real time social data APIs

Tags: api, social-media

Similar question might have been asked before, but APIs are in constant flux and my question is quite specific.

At this point, are there any other free public real time social data APIs similar to Twitter's Streaming API?

Answer (score 1):

Try Meetup.com's streaming API: http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/stream/2/open_events/

For reference, I typed this search query in Google: "free public streaming api -twitter"

Comment: This is not what I had in mind. I'm only interested in major social networks and meetup is not exactly one of them.

Answer (score 0):

A significant number of *free public* APIs are available through the [Mashape API Marketplace](https://market.mashape.com) (*freemium* and *commercial* ones are available as well). For example, their *social data APIs* can be found here: https://market.mashape.com/explore?tags=Social. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but absolute majority of those are through 3rd parties (therefore unreliable), not real time, insignificant.

Comment: @Caballero: You're welcome. Then I don't see the point in your question. Just visit websites of the social network platforms of your interest and check whether they offer "free public real time social data APIs" and information on how to access them, if any.

Comment: I did, they're all tightening the noose around their APIs, so I posted this question in hope that I've missed something.

Comment: @Caballero: I see. I wish I could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few streaming public APIs:

- [Flickr feed](https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/)
- [Facebook public feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) (limited access)
- [Instagram realtime feed](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)

[plenty more here (62 in total)](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/62-real-time-apis-twitter-thrutu-and-pusher/2012/04/17)